# Validating Cell Input Based on Another Cell

Tags: vba, excel

When I input some text in a cell, for example in cell B2-`test`, I want in cell `A6` the input to begin with this string and to end with `_VAR1`-for example `test_VAR1`.

I have found a simple solution as formula - `=IF(A2="test","test_VAR1")` but I want to make it as a VBA code.

So any idea how this can be done?

Comment: What is the connection between `B2` and `A6`?

Comment: There is no specific connection, the B2 cell is in an ID value and is passed as a variant in column Variant Information-it looks like this  http://prntscr.com/jtzs71

Comment: You can use just a formula for that - no need to test what's in B2 if you want to just append `_VAR1` to it.  Just a formula that says _take that value of cell B2 & stick _VAR1 on the end_.

Comment: Are you planning on using `test_VAR1` as a variable within the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most minimal example that I can come up with. 
The `LCase(Range("B2"))` would also take "Test" and "TeSt" into account:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    With ActiveSheet
        If LCase(.Range("B2")) = "test" Then
            .Range("A6") = .Range("B2") & "_VAR1"
        End If 
    End With

End Sub
```

And if you want to check every event of the worksheet, put your code in the corresponding worksheet (Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3 on the picture below):

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If LCase(Target) = "test" Then
        Me.Range("A6") = Target & "_VAR1"
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: probably would be a good idea to add Trim to the LCase to take extra whitespaces into account `Trim(LCase(.Range("B2"))) = ...`

Comment: @Rawrplus - probably

Comment: Is there a way this algorithm to me made more dynamically and to work with any string in cell B2?

Comment: @Hris - delete the if condition?

Comment: it was ok until my `before save` method stopped working maybe because of the disabled events

Comment: I put everything in this method to prevent dsving until all errors are fixed

Comment: @Hris - Can you see the line `Application.EnableEvents = True` on my code?

Comment: Yes , I see it.

Comment: @Hris - it is used to EnableEvents back. Thus, the `Before_Save` should be working.

Comment: But in my case it is not working, I don`t know why suddenly it stops running

Comment: In my case it is :  Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)   `code' End Sub

Comment: Write `Application.EnableEvents = True` in some module. Or in the immediate window,. Or start from an empty Excel Worksheet (easier).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172961/discussion-between-hris-and-vityata).

Answer (score 0):

I know you said in your question you wanted macro, but I'm not going to post my own *(because I feel like @Vityata's answer should be sufficient)*

**However, I got impression from your post, that you could adjust / improve your formula instead and avoid macro altogether.** It's usually better to avoid macro, when possible, for compatibility reasons (a lot of users have macros disabled by default)

1. If you simply want to **add the keyword "_VAR1" to the input**, use the following formula instead
   `=LTRIM(B2) & "_VAR1"`
2. If the input can be anything, that **contains the word "test"**
   `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("test", TRIM(LOWER(B2)))), LTRIM(B2) & "_VAR1", "Incorrect Input")`
3. The text **contains only the word "test" and nothing else**
   `=IF(TRIM(LOWER(B2))="test", LTRIM(B2) & "_VAR1", "Incorrect input"`

There are some other variations / tricks you could do with this, but these are some of the most basic examples you can use as your "building blocks"